# JSF component disappears after binding

Tags: jsf

I defined a custom component and tried to use binding as the following:

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <div>
        <f:subview>
            <a4j:outputPanel>
                <h:commandButton id="t1" value="test!" />
                ...
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </f:subview>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

This component works properly until I added a binding attribute like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="t1" binding="#{foo}" value="test!" onclick="alert('I am #{id:cid(foo)}'); return false;" />
```

This component doesn't show up, and I can't find the corresponding piece of code for this button.

Anyone knows a fix?

Comment: Shoudn't the binding be to a property of a bean like #{bean.prop}? Or did you just leave that detail out? If you actually have it bound to a property can you show the code for the getter and setter?

Comment: @Eelke Thanks for the reply. I did exactly the same thing as I showed above. It should work as described here: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ca/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html#componentbindingclientid.

Comment: Is this template included multiple times?

Comment: @BalusC yes, it is used multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *yes, it is used multiple times*

There's the cause. The `binding` should refer an **unique** reference for the component. Right now you've physically multiple components referring to one and same reference.

I'm not sure what's the concrete functional requirement is, but more than often this approach is unnecessary when you're already inside the JavaScript context. The particular example can then also just be solved as follows:

```
<h:commandButton id="t1" value="test!" onclick="alert('I am ' + id); return false;" />
```

The ID of the generated HTML element itself is namely exactly the same as JSF component client ID.

Comment: Thanks. But the original purpose of using binding here is because this component is used in every row of a datatable and the button text is supposed to be updated on click. I tried to identify the component using id but since it is inside a datatable, I do need the client id instead.

Comment: Then the example in my answer still applies, or better,  `onclick="value='updated!'; return false;"`.

Comment: If it's in the same row, just use `var labelId = button.id.substring(0, button.id.lastIndexOf(':') - 1) + 'labelId';` and then pass it to `document.getElementById()`.