# Binding multiple components to one instance in backing bean (Primefaces Tree)

Tags: jsf, binding, jsf-2, primefaces, components

I want to be able to have a Primefaces tree in 2 places on my page. The reason is that I want to have the two trees with the same data have exacly the same state- the same nodes expanded etc. I tried to bind both instances to the same value in backing bean but this results in only one of them rendering. Am I doing it wrong? Should this be solved differently?

The related question (with slightly different requirements) states that one should not do this, but if not- what should be done?

[JSF component disappears after binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953438/jsf-component-disappears-after-binding)

**Edit 1**

I have noticed that I can share the selection value easily with the 'value=', but the real problem is sharing which nodes are expanded and which are collapsed. I do not know if this is stored on the server, or if it can be stored on the server at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I tried to bind both instances to the same value in backing bean but this results in only one of them rendering. Am I doing it wrong?*

This is definitely wrong. Each component `binding` should resolve to an **unique** request scoped property which is not shared by any other component, nor lives longer than the request scope.

---

> *Should this be solved differently?*

Bind them to different properties. If you want a dynamically expansible property, use a `Map<String, UIComponent>`.

```
private Map<String, UIComponent> components = new HashMap<String, UIComponent>();

// Getter (no setter necessary).
```

which can be used as

```
<x:someComponent binding="#{bean.components.foo}" />
<x:someComponent binding="#{bean.components.bar}" />
<x:someComponent binding="#{bean.components.baz}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually solved my problem by making the trees dynamic and share the same selectedNode. Binding to the same variable was definitely not the way to do it ;)